# QMake install header files (copy to system's include directory)

Tags: c++, qt, header, copy, qmake

What variables and `qmake`-commands can I use to install (copy) header files of my qt-project to system's include directory (for example - `/usr/include`)?

I have tried an approach:

```
header_files.files = $$HEADERS
header_files.path = project/
INSTALLS += header_files
```

but it installs files not to include dir (of course because we have not set it). I've searched a variable in [QMake Variables](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html) but did not found any useful.

Answer (score 3):

You should make header_files.path the directory you want them to install into.

```
header_files.path = /usr/include
```

And the files you want to install should be in the header_files.files variable

```
 header_files.files = directory_for_headers/*
```

Edit: If you need a cross-platform solution, you need to know the default include directories of your target system, and use it like this:

```
 win32: header_files.path = win32_include_directory
 linux: header_files.path = linux_include_directory
```

Edit: But I think if the user compiles with mingw, it should automatically put them in mingw's include directory, so you may need to use either /include or /usr/include. I'm not sure of that though. You need to test it on a Win machine.

Comment: Nice, but I also need crossplatform solution for `/usr/include`.

Comment: You need to define the platforms for that, and change the directory for the platform. I will edit to show that.

Comment: Okay, I'll test it next week, thanks for the response.

Comment: On mingw, it should be same as your INCLUDEPATH. Just for the record. I haven't installed anything in include directory, so I'm not very sure.